# ZipArchive class PHP security issue

Tags: php, linux, security

I have the following PHP code

```
// Check if the upload is setted
if
(
    isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && 
    isset($_FILES['file']['type']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['type']) &&
    isset($_FILES['file']['size']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['size'])
)
{
    $UploadIsSetted = true;
    $UploadIsBad = false;

    $UploadExtension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if the upload is good
    require "../xdata/php/website_config/website.php";
    $RandomFoo = rand(1000999999,9999999999);

    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < ($MaxAvatarPictureSize*1000000)))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            $UploadIsBad = true;
            $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("Error","true");
            $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("SomethingWrong","true");
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../upload/tmp/".$RandomFoo.".file");    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The file is too big
        $UploadIsBad = true;
        $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("Error","true");
        $hrefs->item(0)->setAttribute("UploadTooBig","true");
    }
}
else
{
    $UploadIsSetted = false;
}

$ZipFile = new ZipArchive;
$ZipFile->open('../upload/tmp/'.$LastFilename.'.zip',ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$ZipFile->addFile('../upload/tmp/'.$RandomFoo.'.file',$RandomFoo.".".$UploadExtension);
$ZipFile->close();
```

now my big concern is that user can upload anything so how can i prevent :

- uploading 2GB 3GB files
- floading
- uploading some kind of twisted exploit that would eventually alter my server security
- buffer overflow
- filenames that have arbitrary code injections

i mean, how secure is this script?

i'm running windows for now, i will switch to linux

Comment: That's too many subquestions at once. Ask for the most important. Else consider [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please.

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four your other questions:

> floading

That's the complex part. Let me google you some ideas:

- [Prevent PHP script from being flooded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155339/prevent-php-script-from-being-flooded)
- [Quick and easy flood protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026640/quick-and-easy-flood-protection) - use a nonce, time+tie it onto a session
- Use a captcha, if it doesn't impair usability too much.

> uploading some kind of twisted exploit that would eventually alter my server 
>   security

Use a commandline virus scanner (`f-prot` or `clamav`) to scan uploaded files. You might use a naive regex scanner in PHP itself (probe for HTMLish content in image files, e.g.), but that's not a factual security feature; don't reinvent the wheel.

> buffer overflow

PHP in general is not susceptible to buffer overflows.

Okay, joking. But you can't do anything in userland about it. But pushing strings around isn't much of a problem. That's pretty reliable and unexploitable in scripting languages, as long as you know how to escape what in which context.

> filenames that have arbitrary code injections

At the very leat you should *most always* use [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) to avoid path traversal exploits. If you want to keep user-specified filenames, a regex whitelist is in order. `=preg_replace('/[^\w\s.]/', '', $fn)` as crude example.

Comment: thank you very much, very useful :) glad to read all of those

Answer (score 0):

Your line `if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < ($MaxAvatarPictureSize*1000000)))` already limits the size of file acceptable to `$MaxAvatarPictureSize` megabytes. Though `$MaxAvatarPictureSize` doesn't appear to be set in the code you provided. My guess that should be 1 or 2 max.
Also not set is `$LastFilename` and probably some others too.

Also place an `if($UploadIsBad === false) { /* do zipping */ }` around the Zipping part to avoid zipping up files which are too large or otherwise invalid.

Comment: and couldn't $_FILES["file"]["size"] be fake? injecting some code? i don't know, i'm not sec expert, but i should become, i'm developing an software ...

Comment: He might as well use [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) as that avoids PHP processing bloated requests already. (Though with non-userfriendly message.)

Comment: Additional check would be to call `filesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])` to check actual size instead of relying on `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` as @RowMinds said.